# calls to 127.0.0.1:3000 reaching server from outside

Tags: nginx

Log reports show attempts to enter a server with

```
https://127.0.0.1:3000
```

If I am not mistaken, this is usually used for accessing a localhost.

Now this is clearly an attempt by some bad actors, as this occurs multiple times from different ip addresses within seconds of each other, from ips with very old sites (thus probably hacked), etc.

a) how is this traffic reaching the server in the first place?
b) they are trying to probe a server's weaknesses, but has anyone have an idea why?
c) how can this be mitigated with nginx?

```
------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : https://127.0.0.1:3000/
  * HTTP Method: GET
  * IP address : 208.100.26.231
  * Parameters : {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
  * Timestamp  : 2019-01-17 13:12:55 +0100
  * Server : www
  * Rails root : /home/deploy/v4/releases/20181214163358
  * Process: 7685

-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

  * session id: [FILTERED]
  * data: {}

-------------------------------
Environment:
-------------------------------

  * HTTPS                                          : on
  * HTTP_VERSION                                   : HTTP/1.1
  * ORIGINAL_FULLPATH                              : /
  * ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME                           : 
  * PASSENGER_CONNECT_PASSWORD                     : [FILTERED]
  * PATH_INFO                                      : /
  * QUERY_STRING                                   : 
  * REMOTE_ADDR                                    : 208.100.26.231
  * REMOTE_PORT                                    : 34080
  * REQUEST_METHOD                                 : GET
  * REQUEST_URI                                    : /
  * ROUTES_47310805116200_SCRIPT_NAME              : 
  * SCRIPT_NAME                                    : 
  * SERVER_NAME                                    : 127.0.0.1
  * SERVER_PORT                                    : 3000
  * SERVER_PROTOCOL                                : HTTP/1.1
  * SERVER_SOFTWARE                                : nginx/1.14.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.3.4
  * action_controller.instance                     : #<HomeController:0x00560ed5f77170>
  * action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner              : #<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x00560ecb4f87f8>
  * action_dispatch.cookies                        : #<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x00560ed5daa6a8>
  * action_dispatch.cookies_digest                 : 
  * action_dispatch.cookies_serializer             : json
  * action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt          : encrypted cookie
  * action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt   : signed encrypted cookie
  * action_dispatch.http_auth_salt                 : http authentication
  * action_dispatch.key_generator                  : #<ActiveSupport::LegacyKeyGenerator:0x00560ed8213670>
  * action_dispatch.logger                         : #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00560ecf735d00>
  * action_dispatch.parameter_filter               : [:password]
  * action_dispatch.redirect_filter                : []
  * action_dispatch.remote_ip                      : 208.100.26.231
  * action_dispatch.request.content_type           : 
  * action_dispatch.request.formats                : [#<Mime::Type:0x00560eca749f30 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=3518762773694847120>]
  * action_dispatch.request.parameters             : {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
  * action_dispatch.request.path_parameters        : {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
  * action_dispatch.request.query_parameters       : {}
  * action_dispatch.request.request_parameters     : {}
  * action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie: {}
  * action_dispatch.request_id                     : 13b86fc9-8500-4d0f-b87a-6801cdfb79b6
  * action_dispatch.routes                         : #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x00560ecf774a50>
  * action_dispatch.secret_key_base                : 
  * action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions       : false
  * action_dispatch.show_exceptions                : true
  * action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt             : signed cookie
  * rack.errors                                    : #<IO:0x00560ec9b0db18>
  * rack.hijack                                    : #<Proc:0x00560ed5f66960@/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:84 (lambda)>
  * rack.hijack?                                   : true
  * rack.input                                     : #<PhusionPassenger::Utils::TeeInput:0x00560ed5f66ca8>
  * rack.multiprocess                              : true
  * rack.multithread                               : false
  * rack.request.cookie_hash                       : {}
  * rack.request.query_hash                        : {}
  * rack.request.query_string                      : 
  * rack.run_once                                  : false
  * rack.session                                   : #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x00560ed5f65218>
  * rack.session.options                           : #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options:0x00560ed5f65088>
  * rack.url_scheme                                : https
  * rack.version                                   : [1, 2]
  * warden                                         : Warden::Proxy:47310859610080 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x00560ed5c75a80>}
```

access.log

```
208.100.26.231 - - [17/Jan/2019:13:11:27 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 1477 "-" "-"
208.100.26.231 - - [17/Jan/2019:13:12:50 +0100] "GET /nmaplowercheck1547727169 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
208.100.26.231 - - [17/Jan/2019:13:12:51 +0100] "GET /HNAP1 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
208.100.26.231 - - [17/Jan/2019:13:12:55 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 1477 "-" "-"
208.100.26.231 - - [17/Jan/2019:13:12:55 +0100] "POST /sdk HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
208.100.26.231 - - [17/Jan/2019:13:12:55 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5303 "-" "-"
208.100.26.231 - - [17/Jan/2019:13:12:55 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
```

error.log

```
2019/01/17 13:12:50 [error] 6768#6768: *6400 open() "/home/deploy/default/nmaplowercheck1547727169" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 208.100.26.231, server: [correct ip of host], request: "GET /nmaplowercheck1547727169 HTTP/1.1", host: "[correct ip of host]"
2019/01/17 13:12:51 [error] 6767#6767: *6401 open() "/home/deploy/default/HNAP1" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 208.100.26.231, server: [correct ip of host], request: "GET /HNAP1 HTTP/1.1", host: "[correct ip of host]"
```

Comment: Can you provide more information.  Is this a cloud hosted machine? With which provider? What is the networking setup?  Is there a firewall?  Is the remote IP address inside or outside your LAN?

Comment: Yes it is hosted in cloud.  I'd rather not name the provider, this may not be my prerogative.  The only accessible ports are 22, 80 (diverted to 443), 443 and 123.  the remote IPs are always outside the LAN

Comment: What are you refering to with the `show attempts to enter a server with https://127.0.0.1:3000`? Is that in your access log in the nginx server? Do you have the nginx acting as a proxy to a backend server like ruby or nodejs?

Comment: You ought to edit the question with some error logs or *something* showing how you identified this traffic.  What's actually running on `localhost:3000`?  with the ports you describe in the comment I assume nginx is proxying to a local application server, and you're viewing access logs from the app server.  Without a sample of the log entries nobody can tell you what their intention is.  That said it's not uncommon to see 404 entries from automated bots trying to exploit outdated packages.  Again without this information anyone would be guessing.

Comment: Yes, nginx and passenger are providing access to an application in ruby. I've edited the question with notification data in case of 404 errors.

Comment: access.log and error.log entries for offending ip appended to question

Comment: Obviously the traffic arrives via nginx, which is open to the world.